# WordPress and One.com - Custom on-page PHP calls

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure if there are any developers who have run into this problem, but I'm having a pretty strange issue with custom PHP calls and hosting on One.com.

I have a site which is using a custom PHP page to run some SQL calls and data processing from the WP database. I am then using a PHP plugin to output the returned data onto the homepage. On my development server (provided by QuickHostUK) there were no issues whatsoever. However, once the site was moved onto the live One.com server, whenever I attempt to update the homepage, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function customFunction() in ...wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/widget.php(45) : eval()'d code:4 
Stack trace: 
#0 ...wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/widget.php(45): eval() 
#1 ...wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/inc/renderer.php(550): phpeverywherewidget->widget(Array, Array) 
#2 ...wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/inc/renderer.php(862): SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->the_widget(Array, Array, 0, 0, 2, false, true, 'w5e8c70370bf93', '') 
#3 ...wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/inc/renderer.php(830): SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->render_widget('w5e8c70370bf93', 0, 0, 2, Array, true) 
#4 ...wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/inc/renderer.php(756): SiteOrigin_Panels_Renderer->re in ...wp-content/plugins/php-everywhere/widget.php(45) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

The `customFunction()` is defined in my child theme's `/inc/custom_funtions.php` file. The outputs are all being echo'd on-screen without any problems at all and I am wondering if this is some issue with One.com's server settings. On my development server, I did not need to specifically `include` my custom functions file at the top of the homepage and when I attempt to do so, I get a whole other restrictions error which I think, again, is because of One.com.

Any help solving this would be great!

Comment: Looks like you'll have to put on your debugging hat then, you should get used to this. Most likely, the file is not being included, or the file is not able to define the function. You should start by eliminating one of those 2 possibilities. P.s. i'm curious why eval() is being used (is it legit, and not malicious?). Try using stream_resolve_include_path on whatever you pass to include/require.

Comment: Oh I see you're using php-everywhere. Oh what a sad plugin :(. This explains eval. If you really must use this, then I don't know, its not surprising you are having problems. Might be a timing issue, perhaps your file is included by your theme after your code is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @JoelM. I'm using PHP-everywhere as it is the simplest way to add PHP as a block using a page builder plugin. If I weren't to use it, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to register blocks via php the normal way, using php files in your theme and not a plugin that evaluates php code stored in a database. I haven't used the new block API yet so I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Shortcodes might also do the job for you, allowing you to keep your code in your theme files, and use a shortcode to invoke that code, and pass parameters to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and advice. After looking through the codex and SiteOrigin's documentation, I think I'm leaning towards shortcodes as the best solution to this. In any case, One.com doesn't seem to like processing global functions on page and I will avoid this in future. One less plugin is also always good in my books!

Comment: If there is a persistent issue with all global functions it probably means you're inside of a namespace and you can access the global scope for functions/constants/etc by prefixing those calls with a backslash, ie. \my_function(). However I would guess that the issue is more because the file the function was defined in was not included (yet). In any case, its almost always a good idea to avoid that plugin, in my opinion.